# Android: How to set the maximum size of a Spinner?

Tags: android, layout, alert, spinner

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner android:text="@+id/AutoCompleteTextView01"
                       android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:width="130dp"></Spinner>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/Chapter" android:width="30dp"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:text=":"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Verse"
              android:width="40dp"></EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

I inflate this layout as an AlertDialog's view. But when I pick a large element, the text fields get pushed out to the right. Is there any way to set the maximum size of the spinner so after choosing an element, it shortens the choice with an ellipsis ("...") or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a `Spinner` set have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` is determined by its content. If you want things ellipsized, that's up to you in your `SpinnerAdapter`, when you create your row Views.

Or, hard-wire an `android:layout_width` that is fixed in size.

Or, instead of using `LinearLayout`, use `RelativeLayout` and structure your rules such that the `Spinner` takes up the remaining space on the row, by anchoring it to the left side of the screen and to the left side of the first `EditText`. Though I'm not 100% certain what then happens if the content is too big -- it probably just gets truncated.

Answer (score 5):

No need to use a custom adapter. Use the android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item and then change it from ellipse marquee to end ellipse. Then set your new change layout file as layout id or use this layout file

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Set spinner **android:background="@null"** to solve the problem.
This will also hide the dropdown icon visibility