# How to limit the Spinner Text

Tags: android

I have a `Spinner` and I want to limit the length of the displayed text, I don't want to limit the dropdown item, only the text displayed on the `Spinner`.

I want to add something like the ems, and ellipsis attributes of a `TextView` to a `Spinner`.

Comment: How do you init the spinner text views? Here is related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6393730/827110

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to set the maximum size of a Spinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390418/android-how-to-set-the-maximum-size-of-a-spinner)